# Range Slider make unequal steps equal distance

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to create a range slider with `[2, 4, 20, 23, 51, 101, 152, 303]` as steps **of equal distance**

-> such as **2** should be as far **from 4** as **51 is from 101** or **101 from 152** ...

```dart
RangeSlider(
  min: 0.0,
  max: 303.0,
  divisions: 10,
  labels: RangeLabels(
    _startValue.round().toString(),
    _endValue.round().toString(),
  ),
  values: RangeValues(_startValue, _endValue),
  onChanged: (values) {
    setState(() {
      _startValue = values.start;
      _endValue = values.end;
    });
  },
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list of required value and assign it to the label as shown below

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double _startValue = 0;
  double _endValue = 7;
  List<int> rangeValues = [2, 4, 20, 23, 51, 101, 152, 303];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        child: RangeSlider(
      min: 0,
      max: rangeValues.length.toDouble(),
      divisions: rangeValues.length,
      onChanged: (rangeValue) {
        setState(() {
          _startValue = rangeValue.start;
          _endValue = rangeValue.end;
        });
      },
      values: RangeValues(_startValue, _endValue),
      labels: RangeLabels(rangeValues[_startValue.toInt()].toString(),
          rangeValues[_endValue.toInt()].toString()),
    ));
  }
}
```

[image: preview]

[image: preview]